# Can I use a design pattern to solve this problem?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm adding a line spacer to various GUI screens depending on screen resolution. Currently in the various GUI classes there are calls to a method which returns the screen resolution and adds a new spacer depending on screen resolution. Depending on the class type the value of the SpacerField can change. Is there a design pattern I can use to refactor the code so that there are less conditionals and it is more object orientated ?

```
Class A:
            if(getScreenResolution() == 360){
                add(new SpacerField(15));   
            }

            if(getScreenResolution() == 460){
                add(new SpacerField(5));    
            }


Class B:
            if(getScreenResolution() == 360){
                add(new SpacerField(35));   
            }

            if(getScreenResolution() == 460){
                add(new SpacerField(15));   
            }
```

Possible solution -

```
add(new SpacerUtils.getSpacerField(this));

public static SpacerUtils {
    static {
        int screenRes  = getScreenRes();
    }

    public static SpacerField getSpacerField(Object obj) {

        if(obj instanceof GuiScreen1 && screenRes == 360){
            return new SpacerField(25);
        }
        else  if(obj instanceof GuiScreen2 && screenRes == 360){
            return new SpacerField(35);
        }

    }
}
```

Something like this ?
For each possible spacer value I need to add a new implementation, in this case I just have one - SpacerSmall.

```
Caller - 
                    Spacer spacer  = new SpacerSmall();

                    if(resolution == 360){
                    add(new SpacerField(0 , spacer.getSpacerValue()));  
                    }


Interface -                 
                    public interface Spacer {

        public int getSpacerValue();

    }

Implementation - 
    public class SpacerSmall implements Spacer{

        public int getSpacerValue() {
            return 15;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can use anything to solve the problem. You shouldn't blindly rely on design pattens to make everything good for you. Just think yourself.

Comment: Let the [layout manager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) do the work.

Comment: @Vlad Ok, I've added a possible solution, what do you think? It contains alot of conditionals which are a bad design pattern ?

Comment: @user470184: well, first, I would split it into two classes implementing the same interface, in order to avoid using `instaneof`. Second, I would try not to check for specific resolutions, but _calculate_ the space amount based on the resolution, so the code will be more generic. I don't think there is a pattern behind this idea.

Comment: @Vlad and @user470184 well, it’s called decomposition and can be considered as one of the basic refactoring patterns.

Comment: @oddy: Well, from that point of view, everything is a pattern. _"Good heavens! For more than forty years I have been speaking prose without knowing it."_ [(c)](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Moli%C3%A8re)

Comment: Thanks for the help, reason im concerned with design patterns is when im explaining my code I need to be able to say why I chose a particular methodology, explaining the design pattern is a way of doing this... I've added another possible solution, can you take a look.

Comment: @Vlad indeed :) But, seriously, not everything is a pattern. From polar point of view code consists of patterns and antipatterns (classical view from GoF). If you want to make your code look better, then you are looking for the way to change bad pieces of code to a good ones (antipatterns → patterns). And if you make some basic stuff like braking code into smaller parts or making code more generic — then, of course, you cannot think about that as applying patterns. Nevertheless, you are applying patterns :)

Comment: @oddy: I could imagine that applying a pattern itself constitutes using a (hypothetical) Patternification pattern :-D

Comment: @user470184: I would define the interface like that: `public interface Spacer { public int getSpacerValue(int resolution); }`. So the calling code would be `Spacer spacer  = new SpacerSmall(); add(new SpacerField(0, spacer.getSpacerValue(resolution)));  }

Comment: @Vlad ha-ha, maaaan, see my answer, we see the same thing :) Well, almost the same :) Spacer cannot give the right value because that value depends on the component (see that A and B classes have different spacer width having the same resolution). So it should be delegated to the component itself (or we need to pass the context to the spacer but doing so will complicate design to a greater extent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only one class. Classes should differ on behavior not on data, you shouldn't even make two different classes based on different data. This brings useless class proliferation. The different configuration could be provided in a constructor.

```
public interface Spacer {

    public SpacerField getSpacer(int resolution);

}

public class MySpacer implements Spacer {

    private Map<Integer, Integer> spacerSize;

    public MySpacer(Map spacerSize<Integer, Integer>) {
        this.spacerSize = spacerSize;
    }

    public SpacerField getSpacer(int resolution) {
        Integer size = spacerSize.get(resolution);
        if (size == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid resolution: " 
                            + resolution);
        }
        return new SpacerField(size);
    }

}
```

This is configuration, it's a good practice to create those instances with a Dependency Injection framework and inject the instances where necessary with setters method.

Even if you don't use a dependency injection framework you can do yourself for now and migrate in the future. Here is how:

```
public class AClassThatUseSpacer {

    private Spacer spacer;

    public void setSpacer(Spacer spacer) {
        this.spacer = spacer;
    }
}
```

And when you use it:

```
AClassThaUseSpacer anInstance = new AClassThatUseSpacer();
Map<Integer, Integer> spacerSize = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
spacerSize.put(360, 15);
spacerSize.put(460, 5);
anInstance.setSpacer(new MySpacer(spacerSize));
```

Comment: So to access the Spacer I can just use - this.spacer.getSpacer(getResolution); ?

Comment: Yes, or simply spacer.getSpacer(resolution); supposing that resolution is a variable holding your current resolution.

Answer (score 2):

In your second example you are applying [delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern). If everything you need is to compose your application to the collection of patterns, then you are on a right way. But if you want to make your code easy to understand, then it’s better to delegate spacer width detection to the objects of classes A and B. Like this, for instance:

```java
public interface SpacerWidthResolver {
    public int getSpacerWidth(int resolution);
}

public class A implements SpacerWidthResolver {
    public int getSpacerWidth(int resolution) {
        int spacerWidth = -1;
        switch (resolution) {
            case 360: {
                spacerWidth = 15;
                break;
            }
            case 460: {
                spacerWidth = 5;
                break;
            }
            default: {
                spacerWidth = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
        return spacerWidth;
    }
}
public class B implements SpacerWidthResolver {
    public int getSpacerWidth(int resolution) {
        int spacerWidth = -1;
        switch (resolution) {
            case 360: {
                spacerWidth = 35;
                break;
            }
            case 460: {
                spacerWidth = 15;
                break;
            }
            default: {
                spacerWidth = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
        return spacerWidth;
    }
}
```

And then, later in your class where you have your `getScreenResolution` method:

```java
public void DoSomething(SpacerWidthResolver component) {
    add(new SpacerField(component.getSpacerWidth(getScreenResolution())));
}
```

This might be not the best solution but nevertheless is better (in terms of OO paradigm) than suggested in your first and second attempts.

**EDIT** Also please notice how @eznme answers to your question. His idea might be more appropriate for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that is easily extensible, like adding more classes like A and B with different values you can do this:

```
    class Z {
            abstract int small();
            abstract int large();
            void doSomething() {
                    if(getScreenResolution() == 360){
                            add(new SpacerField(this.small()));   
                    }
                    if(getScreenResolution() == 460){
                            add(new SpacerField(this.large));    
                    }
            }
    }
    class A extends Z {
            int small() {
                    return 15;
            }
            int large() {
                    return 5;
            }
    }
    class B extends Z {
            int small() {
                    return 35;
            }
            int large() {
                    return 15;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A:
private static Map<Integer, Integer> spacerMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{put(360, 15);put(460, 5);};};
...
add(new SpacerField(spacerMap.get(getScreenResolution())))

class B:
private static Map<Integer, Integer> spacerMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{put(360, 35);put(460, 15);};};
...
add(new SpacerField(spacerMap.get(getScreenResolution())))
```